# How can i optimize the code, so vba wont crash?

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following code and the last part of the code always makes vba go inactive. how can i adapt the code, so it is more efficient?

Is there a smarter way to operate the variables of the loop? because i have i and e, in order to keep track of where in the list i am and start the loop again for the if loop

```
Sub Run()
   Dim aRng As Range
   Set aRng = Range("A4:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    'Copy Arng to Col C, and remove duplicates
    With aRng
        .Copy .Offset(, 2)
        .Offset(, 2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        With aRng.Offset(, 2)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        End With
    End With
    'Define and Set rng
    Dim cRng As Range: Set cRng = Range("C4:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)

    With cRng
        With .Offset(, 1) 'Use offset to insert formula to count duplicates
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=countif(C[-3]:C[-3] ,R[]C[-1])"
            .Value = .Value 'Use .Value = .Value to remove the formula
        End With
    End With

    'Remove all characters before "Domain" and put in Col E
    With cRng
        For Each i In cRng
           i.Offset(, 2).Value = "=RIGHT(RC[-2],LEN(RC[-2])-FIND(""@"",(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""_"",""@"",LEN(RC[-2])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""_"",""""))-1)),1))"
           .Value = .Value

           'Test for "DES_" and if True write "DES" or if False write "Not DES" in Col F
           If Left(i.Value, 4) = "DES_" Then
               i.Offset(, 3).Value = "DES"
           Else: i.Offset(, 3).Value = "Not DES"
           End If
        Next i
    End With
```

This part makes vba have a hard time

```
    Dim a As String

    With cRng
        For Each i In cRng
            For Each e In cRng
                If Left(i.Value, 4) <> "DES_" Then
                    a = i.Offset(, 2).Value

                    If Left(e.Value, 4) = ("DES_") And Right(e.Value, Len(a)) = a Then
                        i.Offset(, 4).Value = "Matching DES found"
                        e = Empty
                        GoTo nextI
                   Else
                       i.Offset(, 4).Value = "unique"
                       GoTo nextE
                   End If
               Else
                   GoTo nextI
               End If
nextE:
           Next e
nextI:
       Next i
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Switching to a Variant Array  approach (search that term on SO) will speed this up enormously.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thx. could you suggest a solution to the last code part? i will then adapt the rest accordingly

Comment: _could you suggest a solution to the last code part?_ I  already have

Comment: The last bit could be done as formula also.  Have you got calculation turned off?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav i also tried with calc off but as i dont have any formula in my sheet, that shouldnt be causing the issue

Comment: @chrisneilsen sorry, so i tried to get into arrays now, but i simply cannot understand how do adapt my code to work with arrays. i cant find anything similar to .offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a refactor of your code to use Variant Arrays.

`Offset` is replaced with a index into the array columns.  Just make sure the array is wide enough to include all the columns you want to Offset into (achieved with `.Resize(, 5)` in the array loading line).

Note: I haven't tried to understand your logic, but simply converted the range refences to Arrays.  You'll need to verify if the results are what you expect

```
Option Explicit ' Top line in module

Sub Run()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aRng As Range
    Dim rw As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set aRng = ws.Range("A4:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    'Copy Arng to Col C, and remove duplicates
    With aRng
        .Copy .Offset(, 2)
        .Offset(, 2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        With aRng.Offset(, 2)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        End With
    End With

    'Define and Set rng
    Dim cRng As Range
    Dim cData As Variant

    Set cRng = Range("C4:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    cData = cRng.Resize(, 5).Value2 '<~~ Copy 5 Columns to Variant Array

    With cRng
        With .Offset(, 1) 'Use offset to insert formula to count duplicates
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=countif(C[-3]:C[-3] ,R[]C[-1])"
            .Value = .Value 'Use .Value = .Value to remove the formula
        End With
    End With

    'Remove all characters before "Domain" and put in Col E
    With cRng.Offset(, 2)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[-2],LEN(RC[-2])-FIND(""@"",(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""_"",""@"",LEN(RC[-2])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-2],""_"",""""))-1)),1))"
       .Value = .Value
    End With

    'With cRng
        'For Each i In cRng
        For rw = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)


           'Test for "DES_" and if True write "DES" or if False write "Not DES" in Col F
            If Left(cData(rw, 1), 4) = "DES_" Then
                cData(rw, 4) = "DES"
            Else
                cData(rw, 4) = "Not DES"
            End If
        Next
    'End With

    Dim a As String
    Dim rw2 As Long

    'With cRng
        'For Each i In cRng
        For rw = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)
            'For Each e In cRng
            For rw2 = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)
                If Left(cData(rw, 1), 4) <> "DES_" Then
                    a = cData(rw, 3)

                    If Left(cData(rw2, 1), 4) = ("DES_") And Right(cData(rw2, 1), Len(a)) = a Then
                        cData(rw, 5) = "Matching DES found"
                        cData(rw, 1) = Empty
                        Exit For
                        'GoTo nextI
                        Exit For
                   Else
                       cData(rw, 5) = "unique"
                       'GoTo nextE
                   End If
               Else
                   'GoTo nextI
                   Exit For
               End If
'nextE:
           Next
'nextI:
       Next
   'End With

   ' Put array back on sheet
   cRng.Resize(, 5) = cData
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! only two issues:
Columns D and E are empty when the macro is finished and the values in column D have blanks between them.
The last part of the macros with unique and DES found gives wrong values.